# html разметка в строке js

Tags: javascript, create-react-app

Может кто нибудь подсказать ? использую create-react-app. есть вот такой компонент -

```js
import React from 'react'
import './Cases.sass'
import {CaseItem} from './CaseItem'
import case_1 from '../img/Cases/case-1.jpg'

class Cases extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            cases: [
                { caseImg: case_1, caseName: 'mysite.ru', caseSpecial: 'Оклейка автомобилей пленкой', caseText: 'Целевая аудитория: бизнес с автопарком, который необходимо забрендировать. Проблема – много трафика на сайте от частников, мало целевой аудитории. Результат: 2 месяца.' }
            ]
        }
    }

    render() {
        let cases = this.state.cases;
        return (
            <section className="cases">
                <div className="container">
                    <div className="row">
                        {
                            cases.map((item, i) => {
                                return(
                                    <div className="col-lg-4 col-md-12">
                                        <CaseItem img={item.caseImg} name={item.caseName} special={item.caseSpecial} text={item.caseText} key={i} />
                                    </div>
                                )
                            })
                        }
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>
        )
    }
}

export default Cases
```

А можно как то прописать в строке - caseText, html разметку? что то типо -

```
" "+<teg>+" Целевая аудитория: "+<teg/>+" бизнес с автопарком..."
```

но так не работает.

Comment: У вас CaseItem есть его и допишите что мог получать ваши данные и обрабатывайте его

Comment: Спасибо. Я просто думал что может как то можно редактировать саму строку непосредственно. Шаблон можно сделать, но кейсов очень много и везде разная разметка будет

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В компоненте CaseItem: `<tag>{this.props.text}</tag>`

Можно написать функцию в Cases которая будет возвращать возвращать jsx

```
  function template(string) {
      return (<i>{string}</i>)
  }
```

(тег i для наглядности)

ну и потом передавать эту функцию в пропсах:

`<CaseItem template={template} />`

ну или передавать результат выполнения:

```
<CaseItem text={template(item.caseText)} />
```

Comment: в компоненте можно конечно так сделать. но разметка будет везде разная, вот я и думал редактировать ее прямо в соответствующей строке с текстом

Comment: @СергейКомыза отредактировал ответ, посмотрите, может быть вас устроит такой вариант

Comment: это не совсем то, но я понял в каком направлении двигаться, спасибо большое за подсказку!

Comment: И заодно позволю себе еще вопрос задать) Раз уж, вы, я так понял, работаете с Реакт. Я, просто, только начал его изучать. Я вот начал делать лендинг, и нужно, чтобы при скролле хедер менял свои стили. Как это можно сделать ? где прописать код ?? у меня все разбито по компонентам: Header, Home и т.д. А событие скролла нужно повесить на document. Вы не делали подобного ?

Comment: нужно использовать компоненты жизненного цикла, тут подойдет componentDidMount, или если это функциональный подход с хуками, то useEffect. Внутри этого метода вешаете на window обработчик события по скроллу ну и функцию которая будет что-то делать при скролле

Comment: аа, кажется понял. спасибо большое!